# FCM Security Alert

Tags: android-security

Security alert

Your app contains exposed Google Cloud Platform (GCP) API keys. Please see this [Google Help Center article](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9287711) for details.

I have an android application uploaded in google play store which uses Firebase for App Cloud Messaging in android. I have recently got an alert from play console that

Security alert : Your app contains exposed Google Cloud Platform (GCP) API keys. Please see this Google Help Center article for details.

Could you please tell anyone to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a good question. What should developers do to avoid this alert?

Comment: Please find my answer about expose GCP https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57347740/google-play-security-alert-about-google-cloud-platform-gcp-api-keys

Comment: Post your alert Message received from the play store.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this warning would come because the google cloud platform api key you are using in your app might be exposed you have to put the restriction on this api key from Google Cloud Console. 
There are two type of restriction 
1. Application Restriction 
2. API Restriction 
Please refer below link
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#api_key_restrictions