# Google Maps API is never satisfied

Tags: google-maps

If I use URL referrer authentication with Geocoding API it says:

```
There was an error while trying to fix the Venues geolocation information: API keys with referer restrictions cannot be used with this API.
```

Which after research I find that this means that Google Maps is looking for IP address authentication.

But if I use IP address authentication with Javascript Maps API it says:

```
JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
Your site URL to be authorized: https://example.com

What can be going on?

How can I fully satisfy the good ol'Google Maps?

Comment: See related https://stackoverflow.com/a/57383084/11742502

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using two different Maps APIs; the client-side JavaScript API and the server-side Geocoding API web service. This means you need 2 API keys; one restricted with [HTTP referrers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#restrict_key) for client-side use, and the other one restricted by [IP address](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key#restrict_key) for web services only.

To learn more on how API key restrictions work check out Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices) on API key best practices.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The worst part is that this is done by a popular wordpress plugin called The Events Calendar (only one API for both services)

Comment: If that plugin does not support using multiple API keys then you can either (1) file a FR (2) edit the plugin's source code yourself to use multiple API keys (3) use another plugin for your map implementation. There may be other alternatives too, but in any case, I strongly advise you against leaving your single API key unrestricted and hence unsecured.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is 3 months old now. But I had the same problem and I found out how to solve this.

As evan said, you need 2 API Keys. And annoyingly, The Events Calendar only have one field for the API Key.
BUT, I found a link here: https://support.theeventscalendar.com/ to https://support.theeventscalendar.com/716190-Using-Google-Maps-API-Key-Restrictions. The page redirects though... But I managed to screen shot parts of it before it redirects and found this snippet: https://gist.github.com/cliffordp/a2ec320313afbc1ffb5f0e5ac654b7fb
(I changed the code to use a define instead because I don't want my API key in git)

This filter will make it possible to have two API KEYS.

Comment: Thanks. I already solved it with that filter some time ago, but forgot to update this thread :) As you say it's weird they don't have one field for each purpose.

Comment: Glad to hear you managed to solve the problem! :D 

I contacted Modern Tribe btw, and they fixed their redirect, so now you can find their information https://theeventscalendar.com/knowledgebase/k/using-google-maps-api-key-restrictions/