# Google New Places API - Your app contains exposed Google Cloud Platform

Tags: java, android, security

Your app contains exposed Google Cloud Platform (GCP) API keys, the Classes:

```
MainActivity->onCreate
```

Please refer to the following article on how to fix the issue:
https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9287711

I am getting this alert from my google play store console after implementing new google places API. I have added restrictions to my API key with my SHA key as well. I have used same line from demo project.

https://github.com/googlemaps/android-places-demos/blob/master/demo/app/src/main/java/com/example/placesdemo/MainActivity.java  (Line no 32)

My code

```
String apiKey = getResources().getString(R.string.google_api_key);

if (!Places.isInitialized()) 
Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), apiKey);
```

these lines are used in Activity  which is causing this issue. I need to know how to fix this issue. Because Google new places API is also my requirement i cannot avoid using these lines in my code.

Comment: There was problem when same apiKey used in other side. Just re-generate this apiKey.

Comment: have tried this, even for new API Key same issue.

Comment: Please check this link, it will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/58116098/9724887

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have directly kept your google api key in `strings.xml` . So any one can easily get your key and use it , if they extracted your apk file , even if you have used proguard it's not going to help you.

These are the steps you can take to help minimize the exposure of API keys

- Get the Api key from server by making a request . That api should work for only the authorized user from your app . Ofcouse even this is not 100% secure but its better than plainly keeping the api key in the app .
- Regenerate your API keys periodically. You can regenerate API keys from the [Credentials](http://Regenerate%20your%20API%20keys%20periodically.%20You%20can%20regenerate%20API%20keys%20from%20the%20Credentials%20page%20by%20clicking%20Regenerate%20key%20for%20each%20key.%20Then,%20update%20your%20applications%20to%20use%20the%20newly-generated%20keys.%20Your%20old%20keys%20will%20continue%20to%20work%20for%2024%20hours%20after%20you%20generate%20replacement%20keys) page by clicking Regenerate key for each key. Then, update your applications to use the newly-generated keys. Your old keys will continue to work for 24 hours after you generate replacement keys
- Adding restrictions to API keys, Check [this](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#api_key_restrictions) section on how to do it

Comment: Thank you! Restrictions are added already. I will get key from server and check.